# Equality on constraints

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, type-constraints

Basically, given `{-# LANGUAGE PolymorphicKinds, ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies #-}` (and more, if necessary), does the `(~)` type-level operator work on type-level expressions of kind `Constraint`?  I tried googling the answer, but had no luck.

Comment: The question is weird, but asked well. Out of curiosity, what would you do with a constraint equality?

Comment: @Daniel Wagner I'm writing a cross-paradigm EDSL that uses a generic function system, and, for various reasons, I can't make use of type classes directly.  I could get away with not using this, but it would lead to extremely clunky types and possibly some unnecessary restrictions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Because types of kind `Constraint` are finite sets of atomic type constraints, you can test their equality very easily.

The `PolyKinds` extension is not necessary, however. Also, there's very few situations when this kind equality would actually be useful, because I don't see a practical way of passing polymorphic constraints as the arguments `c1`, `c2` to `Bla`, so the constraint equality would be a tautology in every case (`Show ~ Show` here):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

type Bla c1 c2 a = (c1 a, c2 a, c1 ~ c2)

foo :: Bla Show Show a => a -> IO ()
foo = print

main = foo "Bla"
```